# Вызов return в конструкторе

Tags: c++, конструктор, return

Подскажите, пожалуйста, разрешено ли вызывать `return` для завершения работы конструктора?

Comment: Конечно. Который ничего не возвращает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В теле самого конструктора использовать `return` разрешено. Но, согласно правилам языка, в обработчике исключения `function-try-block` конструктора использование `return` запрещено:

> If a return statement ([stmt.return]) appears in a handler of the function-try-block of a constructor, the program is ill-formed.

т.е.

```
struct some
{
    some() try {
        //Тело конструктора
        return; //Ок
    } catch (...) {
        //Обработчик исключения function-try-block
        return; //Ошибка!
    }
};
```

Comment: а почему так???

Comment: пока искал ответ, нашел, что человек с [700к репы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895888/9245265) написал в ответе к вопросу `return` в `catch`. Правда это было давно

Comment: @SKIP при достижении конца обработчика, исключение снова выбрасывается. Если бы return был разрешен, то это позволило бы игнорировать исключение и пользоваться мертвым объектом.

Comment: @SKIP это верно только для `function-try-block`! В ответе по ссылке в этом плане всё правильно